# AWS SES message stream?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ses, postmark

I'm currently using Postmark for sending emails but considering migrating to AWS SES for cost savings. One feature I value in Postmark is the ability to organize emails into separate message streams, each with its own suppression list. This helps me manage different types of emails effectively.

Is there an equivalent feature in AWS SES that allows for the segmentation of emails into separate streams with their own suppression lists?